# Error al obtener ubicacion del usuario - GPS Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocalización, gps

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones para Android y estoy creando una aplicacioon la cual hace uso de la ubicacion del ususario. El problema es que aveces me entrega una Lat y Long de (0,0). Es decir, no puede leerla.
Pero esto solo pasa con ciertos dispositivos, los cuales no siguen ningun patron en comun.

Realmente desconozco el problema y pienso que puede ser debido a que el sistema no alcanza a obtener estas coordenadas cuando la aplicacion las pide.

El codigo que utilizo para sacar la ubicacion del ususario es elsiguiente:

```
 private Location getMyLocation() {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location myLocation;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

    }
    myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    try
    {
        //El if es para que nos deje de mostrar el "checkpermission", y nos deje obtener la localizacion
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {

            if (myLocation == null)
            {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            if (myLocation == null)
            {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
                myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    return myLocation;

}
```

El error que me marca es el siguiente:

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference"

Comment: ¿Dudo que este sea el problema, pero te has fijado en si la API del proyecto es admitida por la versión de android de esos dispositivos? A mí me paso algo parecido al usar maps para mostrar una localización y dependía de la versión de android.

Comment: estas revisando si tienes el permiso pero no lo estas requiriendo manualmente, al asignarlo la variable myLocation tendría un valor != null @AlanOliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando el location manager no es capaz de regresar una ubicación en ese momento, puedes colocar un listener para que cada lapso de tiempo o cierta distancia se actualice y te regrese una ubicación. En este ejemplo, la distancia es 0 y el tiempo es 0, por lo que te intentara regresar la ubicación inmediatamente.

Es necesario que implementes `LocationListener` o lo coloques en el `requestLocationUpdates`

```
Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if(location!=null){
    //haz lo que necesites con tu ubicacion
} else{
   mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

.......

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        Log.v(TAG, location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
        //en el if de arriba no fue capaz de regresar la ubicacion, asi que entro al listener y aca ya es una ubicacion valida
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this); //para remover el listener y solo escuchar el cambio de ubicacion 1 vez           
    }
}

// metodos requeridos por el LocationListener
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
```

Para agregar el `LocationListener` tienes 2 opciones, una, hacer implements en tu activity o fragment o en donde lo necesites usar. Te daras cuenta que el IDE si usas android studio al menos, te indicara en color rojo que hay un error, puedes presionar ALT+Enter y te saldra una ventana como esta, que te indica los metodos que deberias implementar (que son los que estan abajo)

[image]
[image]

```
public class MiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}  
    //etc etc tus metodos y lo demas

    //aca es donde te va a pedir que sobre escribas los metodos
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
    // metodos requeridos por el LocationListener
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
}
```

La otra opcion es que lo utilices directamente en el location manager

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,new LocationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //aca es donde validas que la ubicacion sea valida, etc 
        }
        //los 3 metodos que se sobre escriben al usar el locationListener
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {}
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {}
    });
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Entonces se supone que en el onLocationChanged ya tengo una ubicacion? Por ultimo,los metodos que mencionas al final, solo son como tal esos? no llevan codigo dentro?

Comment: los metodos que agregue, es necesario que los agregues por el  LocationListener, pero para lo que necesitas no los vas a necesitar. Y en el onLocationChanged, si, ya tendrias una ubicacion valida, pero ten en cuenta que si no se llega a llamar el metodo, posiblemente el gps de tu dispositivo no funcione. Justo ahora tengo un dispositivo que si me regresa la ubicacion y otro en el que el gps no funciona y el onLocationChanged nunca se ejecuta

Comment: tambien como dice @Jorgesys, si es Android 6 o superior, tienes que agregar al manifiesto el permiso de lectura de ubicacion y solicitar el permiso en tiempo de ejecucion.

Comment: Se escuchara muy tonto, pero... Donde se coloca el metodo onLocationChanged? Me marca error al quererlo colocar in importar el lugar.

Comment: @AlanOliver  lo que tienes que hacer es agregar implements LocationListener en la clase que lo necesites, usualmente es un fragment o activity, te dejare ejemplo en la respuesta para que tenga mejor formato

Answer (score 0):

El problema indica que estas tratando de llamar `getLatitude()` en una instancia de `Location` con valor null:

> "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double
>   android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference"

el problema ocurre porque el proveedor que usas no esta disponible, debes activarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te sugiero validar solo obtener los valores de latitud y longitud si el valor de la instancia `Location` es diferente a null:

```
if(myLocation != null) {

    //Obtener valores
}
```

---

También veo que agregaste el bloque para validar si tienes el permiso pero no lo estas requiriendo por lo tanto `myLocation` tendría un valor null, debes agregar la petición del permiso dentro de este bloque:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 120);
```

de esta forma se mostraría el dialogo para aceptar los permisos requeridos para dispositivos Android 6.0 o superior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este sería el código:

```
private Location getMyLocation() {

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location myLocation;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.



      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 120); //*** Agrega la petición!

    }
    myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
...
...
```

Comment: La documentación para `getLastKnownLocation` dice: *If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.* Posiblemente cuando no se tienen los permisos.

Comment: @Klaimmore gracias!, de hecho en realidad el problema es que el proveedor seguramente no esta activo, en este caso el GPS y de esta forma también se obtiene null! Lo relacionado a los permisos es un plus :-\

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Con respecto a lo que mencionas, el provedor si esta activado (En modo precision alta), pero como mencione, no se por que no obtiene las coordenadas.  Con respecto al request que solicita, ese lo mandaba llamar al inicio o por primera vez al ejecutar la aplicacion. Es necesario volverlo a hacer aqui?

Comment: @AlanOliver la petición del permiso regularmente se realiza al iniciar la aplicación si ya se solicito no es necesario nuevamente, solo que veo tienes un bloque vació en el cual determina si tienes permisos que entonces no sería necesario. Para el provider GPS no definas Criteria y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Es que ese bloque de codigo me lo pide para poder hacer uso [myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);]. Ya elimine el criteria y el error sigue apareciendo